# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and '() -> String'

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var token: String?

    func settoken(newtoken: String){
        token = newtoken
    }

    func gettoken() -> String{
        return token!
    }

    func gotoverifyphone(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let verifyphone = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "verifyphone")
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
            self.present(verifyphone, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any){
        ...some code
        let newtoken = json["message"] as? String
        self.settoken(newtoken: newtoken!)
        self.gotoverifyphone()
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class VC_VerifyPhone: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnVerifyPressed(_ sender: Any){
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let token = "Bearer " + ViewController.gettoken(ViewController)
// the line above shows Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and '() -> String'
        request.addValue("authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: token)
    }
}
```

VC_VerifyPhone.swift

On the 2nd last line of the 2nd class, it shows the error:

Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and '() -> String'

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Now I'm getting this error:

Instance member 'gettoken' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the very instance of `ViewController`. which invoked the `VC_VerifyPhone`.

You may need to pass `self` when opening the `VC_VerifyPhone` or some closure returning the same value as `gettoken()` or there may be some other ways. But anyway you need to pass some info from `ViewController` to `VC_VerifyPhone`.

Why don't you pass the token directly?

In your `UIViewController`:

```
func gotoverifyphone(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let verifyphone = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "verifyphone") as! VC_VerifyPhone
    verifyphone.passedToken = token //<- pass your token directly
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
        self.present(verifyphone, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In `VC_VerifyPhone`:

```
var passedToken: String?

@IBAction func btnVerifyPressed(_ sender: Any){
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    if let passedToken = passedToken { //Use the passed token here
        let token = "Bearer " + passedToken
        request.addValue("authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: token)
    } else {
        //This may never happen, but you may need some output while debugging.
        print("VC_VerifyPhone opened without setting `passedToken`")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've been bitten by a bit of Swift fun/weirdness/etc. depending on your point of view!

`gettoken()` is an *instance* method of the `ViewController` class and should be called on an instance. E.g something like:

```
var myViewController : ViewController = ...
...
let token = myViewController.gettoken()
```

You have not done this, instead you've called it on the *class* itself which isn't the same thing at all. You need an *instance* of your *ViewController* class on which to call `get token()`.

**Why the confusing error?**

For reasons I won't attempt to explain Swift 4 (at least, Swift is a moving target) allows you to write:

```
myViewController.gettoken()
```

as

```
ViewController.gettoken(myViewController)()
```

And this is partly what you wrote and the error messages refers to this form.
(For the terminally curious think of instance methods having a type of the form *class -> arguments -> result* and being members of the class.)

Comment: This makes sense, but then how can I transfer the token to the 2nd view? Because if I create a new instance of ViewController in the 2nd view to call gettoken() on, it won't have any token set.

Comment: How you pass values of any kind between different objects (view controllers in this particular) case is a question of your overall program design and a much bigger question to which there is no single answer. Consider how you pass other values around, think about just passing on the token and not the view controller itself, etc. If you can't figure out how to structure your app you'll need to ask a new question, present enough of your app design to explain the issue, say what you've tried, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The way that your code is structured requires you to have an instance of `ViewController`, which has its `token` property set. Once you have that, then you can substitute `viewController.getToken()` for `ViewController.gettoken(ViewController)`.

You first need a view controller with a token. For example:

```swift
let controller = ViewController()
controller.settoken(newtoken: "abc123")
```

Then, you can call `controller.getToken()` and interpolate that into your string, which looks like this:

```swift
let token = "Bearer " + controller.getToken()
```